# Errors RSpec while testing API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec, tdd

just starting to learn RSpec and TDD, and can't figure out why it's don't work at all.

```html
#spec/api/event_api_spec.rb
describe 'Messages API' do
  it 'check response' do
    get 'api.mydomain.dev/events'
    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    # test for the 200 status-code
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

I have create my API on api.mydomain.dev and my folder structure looks like app/controllers/api/events_controller.rb

So when I tried to run bundle exec rspec it's shown that

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MessagesAPI:0x007fc34900cee0>
```

if I'm trying to make smth like Event.creat!(:name => 'My Event') in My Spec file #spec/api/event_api_spec.rb   it says

`NameError:
       uninitialized constant Event`

So i don't understand How require my app/controllers/api/events_controller.rb file to the Spec file to get instance of my Event Class to get it work.

With default controllers it's work fine, I only interesting in API setup, thx

Answer (score 0):

"get" is a method available on controller specs, try with something like

```
describe 'Messages API', type: :controller do
```

to tell rspec you are testing something like a controller, or maybe just do

```
describe EventsController do
```

About the "uninitialized constant Event", try with this at the begning of spec/api/event_api_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

Hope this helps, but your post is a little confusing, is not clear if your  api is online or what, you shouldn't test agains the online api, you should test locally, specs should never communicate with the real world unless it's really really necessary.